# One simple question related to probability equations convertion

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Why

$$\begin{align*}
l(\theta) &= \sum^m_{i=1} \log p(x^{(i)};\theta) \\
&= \sum^m_{i=1} \log \sum_{z(i)} p(x^{(i)},z^{(i)};\theta)
\end{align*}$$

Find this equation from cs229-2018 problem-set3.4(semi-supervised EM)

[image]

What is the logic behind this how it becomes two summations?
Where is $z^{(i)}$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just applies the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$
P(A) = \sum_i P(A, B_i)
$$

Comment: In this problem context, what does $z$ represent? some useless data? Why it introduce one more $z$?

Comment: @Yiffany you tell me, I don't have access to your materials to tell you anything else beyond the quote you posted.